# Which firmware for the AMD Ryzen 5 2500U?

Tags: firmware

I want to install the latest firmware for my APU. I already installed the microcode.

Kernel config (make menuconfig)

```
Device Drivers  --->
    Generic Driver Options  --->
        Firmware loader  --->
(amd-ucode/microcode_amd_fam17h.bin) Build named firmware blobs into 
(/lib/firmware) Firmware blobs root directory
...
```

enter the name of the binary and compile.

Which **amdgpu** firmware is the right one for the **8 × AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx** Processors**?**
There are so many firmware´s in the **/lib/firmware/amdgpu/** directory, i don´t know which one to choose. I think its got to be a **vegam*.bin** or **vega10*.bin**.

```
vega10_acg_smc.bin
vega10_asd.bin
vega10_ce.bin
vega10_gpu_info.bin
vega10_me.bin
vega10_mec2.bin
vega10_mec.bin
vega10_pfp.bin
vega10_rlc.bin
vega10_sdma1.bin
vega10_sdma.bin
vega10_smc.bin
vega10_sos.bin
vega10_uvd.bin
vega10_vce.bin
vegam_ce.bin
vegam_me.bin
vegam_mec2.bin
vegam_mec.bin
vegam_pfp.bin
vegam_rlc.bin
vegam_sdma1.bin
vegam_sdma.bin
vegam_smc.bin
vegam_uvd.bin
vegam_vce.bin
```

carrizo_ce.bin
carrizo_me.bin
carrizo_mec2.bin
carrizo_mec.bin
carrizo_pfp.bin
carrizo_rlc.bin
carrizo_sdma1.bin
carrizo_sdma.bin
carrizo_uvd.bin
carrizo_vce.bin
fiji_ce.bin
fiji_mc.bin
fiji_me.bin
fiji_mec2.bin
fiji_mec.bin
fiji_pfp.bin
fiji_rlc.bin
fiji_sdma1.bin
fiji_sdma.bin
fiji_smc.bin
fiji_uvd.bin
fiji_vce.bin
polaris10_ce_2.bin
polaris10_ce.bin
polaris10_k_smc.bin
polaris10_mc.bin
polaris10_me_2.bin
polaris10_me.bin
polaris10_mec2_2.bin
polaris10_mec_2.bin
polaris10_mec2.bin
polaris10_mec.bin
polaris10_pfp_2.bin
polaris10_pfp.bin
polaris10_rlc.bin
polaris10_sdma1.bin
polaris10_sdma.bin
polaris10_smc.bin
polaris10_smc_sk.bin
polaris10_uvd.bin
polaris10_vce.bin
polaris11_ce_2.bin
polaris11_ce.bin
polaris11_k_smc.bin
polaris11_mc.bin
polaris11_me_2.bin
polaris11_me.bin
polaris11_mec2_2.bin
polaris11_mec_2.bin
polaris11_mec2.bin
polaris11_mec.bin
polaris11_pfp_2.bin
polaris11_pfp.bin
polaris11_rlc.bin
polaris11_sdma1.bin
polaris11_sdma.bin
polaris11_smc.bin
polaris11_smc_sk.bin
polaris11_uvd.bin
polaris11_vce.bin
polaris12_ce_2.bin
polaris12_ce.bin
polaris12_mc.bin
polaris12_me_2.bin
polaris12_me.bin
polaris12_mec2_2.bin
polaris12_mec_2.bin
polaris12_mec2.bin
polaris12_mec.bin
polaris12_pfp_2.bin
polaris12_pfp.bin
polaris12_rlc.bin
polaris12_sdma1.bin
polaris12_sdma.bin
polaris12_smc.bin
polaris12_uvd.bin
polaris12_vce.bin
raven_asd.bin
raven_ce.bin
raven_gpu_info.bin
raven_me.bin
raven_mec2.bin
raven_mec.bin
raven_pfp.bin
raven_rlc.bin
raven_sdma.bin
raven_vcn.bin
stoney_ce.bin
stoney_me.bin
stoney_mec.bin
stoney_pfp.bin
stoney_rlc.bin
stoney_sdma.bin
stoney_uvd.bin
stoney_vce.bin
tonga_ce.bin
tonga_k_smc.bin
tonga_mc.bin
tonga_me.bin
tonga_mec2.bin
tonga_mec.bin
tonga_pfp.bin
tonga_rlc.bin
tonga_sdma1.bin
tonga_sdma.bin
tonga_smc.bin
tonga_uvd.bin
tonga_vce.bin
topaz_ce.bin
topaz_k_smc.bin
topaz_mc.bin
topaz_me.bin
topaz_mec2.bin
topaz_mec.bin
topaz_pfp.bin
topaz_rlc.bin
topaz_sdma1.bin
topaz_sdma.bin
topaz_smc.bin
vega10_acg_smc.bin
vega10_asd.bin
vega10_ce.bin
vega10_gpu_info.bin
vega10_me.bin
vega10_mec2.bin
vega10_mec.bin
vega10_pfp.bin
vega10_rlc.bin
vega10_sdma1.bin
vega10_sdma.bin
vega10_smc.bin
vega10_sos.bin
vega10_uvd.bin
vega10_vce.bin
vegam_ce.bin
vegam_me.bin
vegam_mec2.bin
vegam_mec.bin
vegam_pfp.bin
vegam_rlc.bin
vegam_sdma1.bin
vegam_sdma.bin
vegam_smc.bin
vegam_uvd.bin
vegam_vce.bin

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/AMDGPU

you should be using `raven_* firmware`

```
~ # echo amdgpu/raven_{ce,k_smc,mc,me,mec2,mec,pfp,rlc,sdma1,sdma,smc,uvd,vce}.bin `
amdgpu/raven_ce.bin amdgpu/raven_k_smc.bin amdgpu/raven_mc.bin amdgpu/raven_me.bin `
amdgpu/raven_mec2.bin amdgpu/raven_mec.bin amdgpu/raven_pfp.bin `
amdgpu/raven_rlc.bin amdgpu/raven_sdma1.bin amdgpu/raven_sdma.bin ` 
amdgpu/raven_smc.bin amdgpu/raven_uvd.bin amdgpu/raven_vce.bin
```